# Data factory: File move

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am working on data factory and was wondering if there are any activities to just "move files" without actually reading them rather than "copy data" (which seems like does a read operation)?

I am trying to move files if any exist from one folder to another and if there are many files, since copy data reads each file, it makes the process slow.

Any suggestion. This is how my current data source looks like and all I want to do is, if there is any csv file exists at the location move it without reading it per say.

[image]

Comment: Instead of csv, if you select binary it will make object copy without reading file line by line

Comment: Thanks Kannan, where do I do that? Which property? Also, I am only interested in moving files of type .csv

Comment: @KannanKandasamy is correct. Binary is a Dataset type in lieu of Delimited. You can control the file name with Dataset parameters at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

So here is a MSFT link I followed to move files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/solution-template-move-files

This tutorial was not very detailed when it comes to explaining everything. Like it assumes that the user needs parameters.  I did as it said but my datasets were pointing to exactly where files need to be picked up and land, so I left the parameters empty. Debugging or running the trigger didn't move a file..  solution didn't work.

I had to remove the parameters created in the template to make this work. In case its helpful to some.  File move started happening after that.

So lesson learned, empty parameters wont work. If you don't need them remove them.

Also, I watched this tutorial in case its helpful to some one.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_X_f4z8zoQ